# SQL: Sum returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have two tables `academy_attempt` & `module_attempt`

I am attempting to add two values from each of these tables together:

```
        round(((select 
                    sum(`academy_attempt`.`score`)
                from
                    `academy_attempt`
                where
                    ((`academy_attempt`.`module_type_id` in (3 , 4, 5, 6))
                        and (`academy_attempt`.`user_id` = `U`.`id`))) + (select 
                    sum(ifnull(`module_attempt`.`score`, 0))
                from
                    `module_attempt`
                where
                    ((`module_attempt`.`module_type_id` in (3 , 4, 5, 6))
                        and (`module_attempt`.`user_id` = `U`.`id`)))),
            2) AS `total_score`
```

in academy_attempt the where statement is met and in one row it returns the right amount (if it is alone) however module_attempt does not have any values that matches the where statement and therefor returns null.

Sadly this does not turn into 0 and since im guessing you can't do the operation: `17 + null = 17` it instead returns `null`.

To counter this i have attempt an `IFNULL` statement as you can see above but sadly this did not fix the problem

Comment: I suspect there is a clearer way to do the calculation you want, one that doesn't involve multiple levels of subqueries in a `select` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not sure there is :S its for a view meaning i cannot use union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the `IFNULL()` higher up, because an empty result set is considered to be `null`:

```
SELECT (... 
) + IFNULL((SELECT SUM(`module_attempt`.`score`) ...), 0) AS total_score
```

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` represents an unknown value, so naturally trying to add an unknown value to a number still results in an unknown value, albeit a different unknown value (hence `NULL != NULL`)

I think you actually want the `COALESCE` function, which returns the first non-null argument. Thus, you can wrap your null value with this function, and sum it as normal. `COALESCE( NULL, 0 )` will return `0`, and `COALESCE(1,0)` will return 1

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: `IFNULL()` works in the same way, except that it only accepts two arguments whereas `COALESCE()` accepts more.